# How to Monitor Multiple Folders?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code in ThisOutlookSession to do something with items I send. It checks the Sent Items folder. It works only for one specified mailbox/folder.

I would like to monitor three mailboxes

I can change the line:

```
Set Items = AInbox.Items
```

and it will work, but only for the mailbox I set it to.

```vb
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim AInbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim BInbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim CInbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Dim AItems As Items
    Dim BItems As Items
    Dim CItems As Items

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set AInbox = GetFolder("a@email.co.ukInbox\Sent Items")
    Set BInbox = GetFolder("b@email.com\Inbox\Sent Items")
    Set CInbox = GetFolder("c@email.com\Inbox\Sent Items")

    Set Items = AInbox.Items
End Sub
     

Public Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        'Do something
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set AItems = AInbox.Items`, `Set BItems = BInbox.Items` and `Set CItems = CInbox.Items`. Then `Public Sub AItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)`, `Public Sub BItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)` and `Public Sub CItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)`

Comment: I tried this previously and it didn't work, so I moved on. Your comment made me revisit it. Stupidly at the top, I had: Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items. I changed this to AItems, BItems and CItems and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may monitor any number of folders.

```
Private WithEvents AItems As Items
Private WithEvents BItems As Items
Private WithEvents CItems As Items
```

then

```
Set AItems = AInbox.Items
Set BItems = BInbox.Items
Set CItems = BInbox.Items
```

then

```
Public Sub AItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Public Sub BItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Public Sub CItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
```